browser_cookie3.BrowserCookieError: Unable to get key for cookie decryption
While using browser_cookie3 python package, the following:
my_domain = 'www.xxx.com'
browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name=my_domain)

generates the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/create_cookies.py", line xx, in main
   x = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name=my_domain)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/browser_cookie3/__init__.py", line 1160, in chrome
   return Chrome(cookie_file, domain_name, key_file).load()
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/browser_cookie3/__init__.py", line 515, in load
   value = self._decrypt(value, enc_value)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/browser_cookie3/__init__.py", line 585, in _decrypt
   raise BrowserCookieError('Unable to get key for cookie decryption')

browser_cookie3.BrowserCookieError: Unable to get key for cookie decryption

Chrome is Version 130.0.6723.70, python is 3.11.9 and browser_cookie3 is 0.19.1.

There is an open pull request fixing this issue at #215.
Until a fix is merged, you can install directly from the PR head:
pip install --force-reinstall git+https://github.com/borisbabic/browser_cookie3.git@refs/pull/215/head


I have no expertise on the topic, so don't ask me why but it seems a header was added to the decrypted value.
I was able to fix it by replacing line:
return decrypted.decode('utf-8')

by:
return decrypted[32:].decode('utf-8')

in file /Users/python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/browser_cookie3/__init__.py

hello, where is is that you could replace this? init is quite long in this library

Found, but not working for me
